# HTML address with arguments (?)

Tags: javascript, html

For example, if you enter https://translate.google.com/#en/la/werwer in browser address bar, it will open https://translate.google.com and fills "translate from" field with "werwer". How is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its done with [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object. You can do it too.

Like this:

```
window.location.hash="werwer";
```

And you can parse it using the same.

```
var hash = window.location.hash; // contains #en/la/werwer
```

Comment: Glad to have helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has access to the page's URL, which contains the "werwer". Pages like that use JavaScript to parse the hash part of the URL to set up the page state when it loads.